# Is there a standard pattern with EntityFramework for assigning Id based on a matching other field?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In C#, I have a number of Item objects that may be created from user input. A user can assign a Label to the Item. The labels are free text but are often the same. Therefore, instead of storing duplicate strings in the database, I have a Label class where each string Value should have one and only one Id.

```
class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ...other properties...
    public Label ItemLabel { get; set; }
}

class Label
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

When executing the Example() method below, the database creates two Label entries, each with different Id values auto-generated.

```
void Example()
{
    // simulate first user...

    var item1 = new Item { ItemLabel = new Label { Value = "alpha" } };

    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        db.Items.Add(item1);
    }

    // simulate second user...

    var item2 = new Item { ItemLabel = new Label { Value = "alpha" } };

    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        db.Items.Add(item2);
    }
}
```

Of course, I realise that this is correct behaviour but I would like the Ids to be the same. Do I have to use a Dictionary to keep track of duplicates in memory, do I have to round trip to the database each time to check for a pre-existing entry or is there a way EF can populate the Id for me, based on a pre-existing matching Value in the database?

In other words, there are clearly ways of solving this myself outside of EF but is there a standard pattern I am unaware of?

Comment: so you want to check in database that if value already exists then update else add new entry?

Comment: No update is required. It either assigns the Id to the object from the database if the Value is found. Otherwise, it auto-assigns a new Id.

Comment: If label names are unique, what prevents you from making it the primary key?

Comment: If you have two people simultaneously creating the same object then you have no way of linking them unless you have a background process or worker role acting on the database to clean duplications

Comment: The puzzle would be how to correctly set the Id property given a newly created object.